# ElasticSearch and Neo4j Java client library in same project

Tags: java, elasticsearch, neo4j, integration

We have been trying to derive Elastic Search query from a Neo4j graph. i.e. Elastic Search java client and Neo4j java client both exist in the same project.
However, both are not running simulatneously.

This is possibly due to multiple lucene jar version used by both the framework.
But my requirement is to have both the client libraries in the same project.

Neo4j version : 3.1
Elastic Search version : 5.2

Is there any way by which both java client libraries for Elastic and Neo4j co exist in same project.

P.S. I am not trying to modify the graph. I looked into Neo4j elasticsearch plugin but it only pushes the changes to elastic search. In my case, the graph will be pre built so no changes as such will be happening in real time.

Comment: When you say same project, are they in a same maven plugin? If so perhaps splitting both client and building them in a parent plugin might help solve your issue. Otherwise, we would need the stacktrace/error you're getting when running your project

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this is a pain. The only solution that we found and are using for testing ES and Neo4j in the same JVM is here:

- https://github.com/graphaware/elasticsearch-tests-integration
- https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-tests-integration

Feel free to dig around and see how it works. Classloader magic.